# Cannot reinstall Snap Store after removing it

Tags: snap, snap-store

My system

```
snap version
 
snap    2.54.4
snapd   2.54.4
series  16
ubuntu  21.10
kernel  5.13.0-39-generic

uname -a

Linux 5.13.0-39-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 15:35:05 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/lsb-release 

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=impish
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.10"
```

I can install all snap packages from the command line, except for snap-store as it fails the configure hook task

```
sudo snap install snap-store
INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "snap-store" snap if present (run hook "configure": sanity timeout expired: Interrupted system call)
```

I have tried to install the store in different ways but they fail the same way

```
sudo snap install snap-store --candidate
sudo snap install snap-store --beta
snap install snap-store --ignore-running --ignore-validation --no-wait
```

And I even tried re-installing the snap environment

```
sudo apt purge snapd
sudo apt install -y snapd
sudo snap install snap-store

error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "snap-store" snap if present (run hook "configure": sanity timeout expired: Interrupted system call)
```

I enabled snapd debugging. Here is the log output when trying to install snap-store

```
SNAPD_DEBUG=1
sudo snap install snap-store
journalctl -u snapd

snapd[23547]: api_snaps.go:307: Installing snap "snap-store" revision unset
snapd[23547]: taskrunner.go:271: [change 5 "Run configure hook of \"snap-store\" snap if present" task] failed: run hook "configure": sanity timeout expired: Interrupted system c>
snapd[23547]: handlers.go:644: Reported install problem for "snap-store" as
```

**Help appreciated!**

Comment: Hello. Please read the title of the question. It reads like you are trying to re install the OS 21.10 You may want to correct this.

Comment: Hopefully it's clearer now